# Jquery: Changing Content of a div modifies its behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, replace, innerhtml

I have a set of images with 2 functionalities.
The first is that I have the thumbnails on the side and when clicked they will appear full size on the side. By default the first image is displayed full size. 
The other works in the big image. It is basically a full screen zoom.

Without switching the images the zoom works fine, but if I replace it, even if clicking its thumbnail (so i't the same image, and the page source code it the same). When clicking it it opens the image instead of zooming.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="images">
<!-- Thumbnails -->
<div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumb">
        <a href="imageroute.jpg" title="Colección Nati Jimenez 2018"
            data-width="700" data-height="990" data-index="0">
            <img src="imageroute.jpg" alt="Colección Nati Jimenez 2018"
                itemprop="image">
            <input type="hidden" value="imageroute.jpg" class="imgFull">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
        <a href="imageroute.jpg" data-width="700" data-height="990"
            data-index="1">
            <img src="imageroute.jpg">
            <input type="hidden" value="imageroute.jpg" class="imgFull">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Big Image -->
<div class="image-big">
    <a href="imageroute.jpg" title="Colección Nati Jimenez 2018"
        data-width="700" data-height="990" data-index="2">
        <img src="imageroute.jpg" alt="Colección Nati Jimenez 2018"
            itemprop="image">
        <input type="hidden" value="imageroute.jpg" class="imgFull">
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery script

```
<script>
var currentScroll = 0;
jQuery(function($) {

    //Stuff

    //Image Change
    $('.thumbnails .thumb').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $contenido = $(this).html();                                
        $('.images .image-big').html($contenido);                                
    });

    //Zoom
    $('.images .image-big a ').click(function(e) {
        if (isMobile.any()) {
             $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
        } else {                                    
            currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // go to top
            $('body').addClass('disable-scrolling'); // disable scroll                                    
        }

        currentIndex = $(this).data("index");

        $('.zoom img').attr('src', $(this).find('.imgFull').val());
        $('.zoom').fadeIn();

        zoom(e, $(this).data('width'), $(this).data('height'));

        return false;
    });

    //More Stuff

});
```

Comment: A possible reason for this behaviour (and I think this is actually the problem) is that the functionalities you bound to the click event of your '.images .image-big a', is removed when you replace the contents of the div. A possible solution is to use a delegate event binder, [http://api.jquery.com/delegate/](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the comment by @qvotaxon suggests, you need to delegate the click event. this means, instead of binding to the actual dom element (which is to be replaced), you listen on the document.

simply replace

```
$('.images .image-big a ').click(function(e) { ... });
```

by

```
$(document).on('click', '.images .image-big a ', function(e) { ... });)
```

Comment: That works!! Anything I should have in mind when using that?Some side effects?

Comment: No harmful side effects to take into account, but I recommend reading the jquery docs for delegates.